# What are potential problems in upgrading matlab from R2011a to R2013a

Tags: matlab

I am currently working in matlab R2011a. These are the tools that I am using

```
neural-network toolbox
curve-fitting toolbox
```

I want to use `forecast and kalman filter` functions which are unavailable in `R2011a` . Hence I am considering to update to `R2013a` . But, I am concerned that all of my functions would give the **exact same** output or not.

Can anyone post some reference or any experience in this matter , so that I can be sure.

Reference or experience to any issues in upgrading the version is appreciated.

Comment: You can install 2013 without uninstalling 2011, so you can test your scripts before uninstalling 2011

Comment: @Dan I am not sure if matlab modifies Registry values or not, it sure modifies the environment path in windows. I believe there may be a conflict. What do you know about this.

Comment: I have 3 versions of Matlab currently installed and all working fine. I can't guarantee it but I'm pretty confident that each install is considered a separate application by your computer

Comment: @Dan thanks for the info, you really saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest going through the release notes for each of those 3 products to check for known compatibility considerations:

- http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/nnet/release-notes.html
- http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/curvefit/release-notes.html

(I don't know what the time series toolbox is, it doesn't seem to be a MathWorks product).

Comment: It is just time-series prediction through neural-network toolbox